# Выборочный вывод данных из json

Tags: jquery, json

проблема состоит в том что у меня в jsone есть два одинокавых данных, но нужно вывести одну

```
 "values":[  
    {  
       "x":"Соотношение выплат к поступлениям  (06-MAR-19-04-APR-19)",
       "y":"1.Поступление",
       "value":804.25
    },
    {  
       "x":"Соотношение выплат к поступлениям  (06-MAR-19-04-APR-19)",
       "y":"2.Выплаты",
       "value":752.69
    }
 ]
```

А сам скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function() { $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/second.json',
    success: function(json) {

var name = [0];

for (index = 0; index < json.data.length; ++index) {
    if (json.data[index]['graphId'] == 5) {
        for (i = 0; i < json.data[index]['values'].length; ++i) {
                    name.push(json.data[index]['values'][i]['x']);

        }
    }
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = name;
}


    }
});
      });
```

он выводит значение x два раза, как сделать чтобы если они одинаковые, то выводился только один?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (name.indexOf(json.data[index]['values'][i]['x']) == -1)
  name.push(json.data[index]['values'][i]['x']);
```

Comment: благодарю за быстрый и нужный ответ)